# How do I get VrVideoView to start in Cardboard mode?

Tags: android, virtual-reality, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

http://trimensions.org/node/83
I am coding by importing the code from the link above.
But this code starts on a small screen.
As soon as I start, I want to start with the Cardboard mode (a mode with both left-eye and right-eye monitors).
However, no matter how I read the code, the code to switch to Cardboard mode is not visible in this code.
I think it is all contained in VrVideoView.
If you know something, let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line after declaring `VrVideoView` variable. I've declared it 'videoWidgetView'.

```
videoWidgetView.setDisplayMode(3);
```

> 1: Mono Display (Normal Screen)
>
> 2: Full Screen
>
> 3: Stereo Screen (CardBoard Mode)

Comment: If it was useful for you, feel free to upvote it